# FastAPI/Pydantic alias existing ORM field

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I need to point [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/) to a different attribute when serializing an ORM model. `alias=` doesn't seem to work as expected. In the example below I have an ORM object with both `id` and `uuid` attributes. I want to serialize `uuid` as `id`.

The API response should be:

```json
{
  "id": "12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Full example:

```py
from uuid import UUID
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from dataclasses import dataclass


class ApiSchema(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

    uuid: UUID = Field(alias='id')
    foo: str | None = None


@dataclass
class ORMModel:
    id: int
    uuid: UUID
    foo: str = 'bar'


app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def endpoint() -> ApiSchema:
    t = ORMModel(id=1, uuid=UUID('12345678123456781234567812345678'), foo='bar')
    return t
```

This raises

```
File fastapi/routing.py", line 141, in serialize_response
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ApiSchema
response -> id
  value is not a valid uuid (type=type_error.uuid)
```

The [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) equivalent of what I'm trying to achieve would be this:

```py
import marshmallow as ma

class ApiSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = ma.fields.UUID(attribute='uuid')
    foo = ma.fields.Str()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand how [aliases](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#reserved-names) work. An alias on a field takes priority (over the actual field name) when the fields are **populated**. That means, during initialization, the class will look for the *alias* of a field in the data it is supposed to parse.

The way you defined `ApiSchema`, the field `uuid` has the alias **`id`**. Therefore, when you are parsing an instance of `ORMModel` (happens in FastAPI behind the scenes via `ApiSchema.from_orm`), the `ApiSchema` class will look for an attribute named **`id`** on that `ORMModel` object to populate the `uuid` field.

Since your `ORMModel` actually *has* an attribute named **`id`** (with the value `1` in your example), its value is taken to be assigned to the `uuid` field of `ApiSchema`.

Obviously, the integer `1` is not a `UUID` object and can not be coerced into one, so you get that validation error telling you that the value it found for **`id`** is not a valid UUID.

Here is the problem boiled down to the essentials:

```py
from uuid import UUID

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ValidationError


class ApiSchema(BaseModel):
    uuid: UUID = Field(alias='id')
    foo: str | None = None


try:
    ApiSchema.parse_obj({"uuid": "this is ignored", "foo": "bar"})
except ValidationError as exc:
    print(exc.json(indent=2))

try:
    ApiSchema.parse_obj({"id": 1, "foo": "bar"})
except ValidationError as exc:
    print(exc.json(indent=2))
```

The output of the first attempt:

```json
[
  {
    "loc": [
      "id"
    ],
    "msg": "field required",
    "type": "value_error.missing"
  }
]
```

The second:

```json
[
  {
    "loc": [
      "id"
    ],
    "msg": "value is not a valid uuid",
    "type": "type_error.uuid"
  }
]
```

---

I think you want it **the other way around**. I assume that your actual goal is to have a field named `id` on your `ApiSchema` model (and have that appear in your API endpoint) and alias it with `uuid`, so that it takes the value of the `ORMModel.uuid` attribute during initialization:

```py
from uuid import UUID

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class ApiSchema(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(alias="uuid")
    foo: str | None = None


obj = ApiSchema.parse_obj(
    {
        "id": "this is ignored",
        "uuid": UUID("12345678123456781234567812345678"),
        "foo": "bar",
    }
)
print(obj.json(indent=2))
```

The output:

```json
{
  "id": "12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

---

To fix your FastAPI example, you would therefore probably do this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from uuid import UUID

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class ApiSchema(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(alias="uuid")
    foo: str | None = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


@dataclass
class ORMModel:
    id: int
    uuid: UUID
    foo: str = "bar"


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/", response_model=ApiSchema, response_model_by_alias=False)
def endpoint() -> ORMModel:
    t = ORMModel(id=1, uuid=UUID("12345678123456781234567812345678"), foo="bar")
    return t
```

Side note: Yes, the actual return type of `endpoint` is `ORMModel`. The wrapper returned by the decorator then takes that and turns it into an instance of `ApiSchema` via [`from_orm`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances).

### PS

Forgot the last part to actually get the response you want. You need to set `response_model_by_alias=False` in the route decorator (it is `True` by default) for the response to actually use the regular field name instead of the alias. I fixed the last code snipped accordingly. Now the response will be:

```json
{"id":"12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678","foo":"bar"}
```

In the Pydantic `BaseModel.json` method the `by_alias` parameter has the value `False` by default. FastAPI does this differently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DaniilFajnberg. This is how I originally expected it to work, but FastAPI is returning 
`{
  "uuid": "12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678",
  "foo": "bar"
}` .  I would expect obj.json() to dump the exact same thing as returning the ORMModel and having ApiSchema dump from orm

Comment: @andy_lu Sorry, forgot that part. I edited the last code piece and explained the difference. You need to set `response_model_by_alias=False` in the route because unlike in `BaseModel.json` the default is actually `True` for FastAPI routes.

Comment: I see.  The issue is that the openapi docs show `uuid` in the return object, but it actually returns `id`.  I think I remember seeing an issue where this was unavoidable at the moment which is a bummer.  Maybe it will be fixed in pydantic v2.